# DetectionAPI supports mono Wav only

Tags: java, android, musicg

I am working on a clap detection android app. i am using [musicg](https://github.com/madyx/musicg) api for this.

I imported the project from github and run on android device. then this error shows - *DetectionAPI supports mono Wav only*

the detail LogCat is-

```
DetectionAPI supports mono Wav only
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.musicg.wave.WaveHeader.getBitsPerSample()' on a null object reference
at com.musicg.api.DetectionApi.isSpecificSound(DetectionApi.java:80)
at com.musicg.api.WhistleApi.isWhistle(WhistleApi.java:54)
at com.musicg.demo.android.DetectorThread.run(DetectorThread.java:106)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

*Do anyone have any suggestion how to solve this ?*

Answer (score 0):

> supports mono Wav only

You should record as a wav file as api mentioned. I would recommend you to check [musicg_android_demo](https://code.google.com/archive/p/musicg/downloads) sources.

Comment: i am using the same code for my demo as you have suggested. but no good. i am getting the exception in the code.

Comment: how do i record a mono wav ?